# Ubuntu 18.04 does not connect to Sony WH-XB910N bluetooth headphones

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, headphones, sony

I try to connect my Sony WH-XB910N bluetooth headphones to Ubuntu 18.04

**Bluez version:**  `bluetoothd -v` gives `5.52`

**Pulseaudio bluetooth:** `pactl list | grep -i module-bluetooth-discover` gives `Name: module-bluetooth-discover`

I hold power button of headphone until bluetooth led starts blinking. Then I go to Ubuntu bluetooth device settings. The device is just not shown in bluetooth list in system settings and not in blueman.

Does somebody have an idea what to do? Any chance to get it running in ubuntu?

Thank you!

Comment: Were the headphones paired with a different computer / other device before?

Comment: They were connected to my mobile phone. But I disabled bluetooth at my mobile phone while trying to connect it to my ubuntu. Do you think I have to reset it somehow?

Comment: No, not really. I asked because according to this https://helpguide.sony.net/mdr/whxb910n/v1/en/contents/TP1000442800.html putting it explicitly in pairing mode is only necessary if it has been connected to other device before ("*the headset has pairing information for other devices*")

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I found it: It`s not a linux problem :)

Headphone had just not been in pairing mode. You need to switch the headphone off (hold power button until voice says "switched off"). Then you need to hold power button then voice says "switched on" and you need to continue hold (do not release), and after a few seconds she says "pairing mode" :)

There are several kinds of how the pairing LED is blinking. And only 2 blinks after one another is the correct one.

Now I have problems with HFP/HSP mode, but this is another story.

Comment: Thank you so much, saved my day :)

Comment: wow at first it seemed dumb to me, till i realised this was me. thanks for saving the day!

Comment: Thanks a lot. you save my day.